# Can an entity have a list/array of items (Core Date, XCode)

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm very new to Core Data and I have two questions:

1. I want that all of my Patient entities have property bed which is a value of type bed... Can I create an entity for that too and connect always one patient with one bed?
2. I wondered if I can do something like every Patient has a property doctors, and that would be a array of doctors "[doctor]". How could I make this.

Thanks, hope you know what I mean, it would be great If someone knows how to do that.

Comment: Yes. The key word you are missing is "relations". You want relationship between your entities. Be it one to one, one to many, many to many.

Comment: Okay, first at all thanks for your quick answer. Can you give an example, how I could make some relations so, that I have an entity, wich contains a list of other entitys?

Comment: Find an online tutorial on learning and using Core Data, many of them handles entity relationships as well

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay *Larme* and *Joakim Danielson* answers my question as comments under my post :)
Their comments:

> Yes. The key word you are missing is "relations". You want relationship between your entities. Be it one to one, one to many, many to many. –

> Find an online tutorial on learning and using Core Data, many of them handles entity relationships as well –

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment

Comment: Yes, but so I can mark this Question as Checked :)